# Join two strings into a callable string 'moduleA' + 'func1' into moduleA.func1()

Tags: python, string, function

I got this:

`tu = ("func1", "func2", "func3")`

And with the operation I am looking for I would get this for the first string:

`moduleA.func1()`

I know how to concatenate strings, but is there a way to join into a callable string?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. "I would get this for the first string" means what? Can you show some interactive console output maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getattr(moduleA, 'func1')()` == `moduleA.func1()`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getattr` builtin function. Try:

```
getattr(moduleA, 'func1')()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean get a function or method on a class or module, all entities (including classes, modules, functions, and methods) are objects, so you can do a `func = getattr(thing 'func1')` to get the function, then `func()` to call it.